# Mongoose remove _id and __v before sending to the front end

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

When I get data from mongo via mongoose with...

```
      const allAssets = await assets
        .find({ company })
        .sort([['createdAt', -1]])
        .exec();
      res.status(200).json({ assets: allAssets });
```

I always get _id and __v  but I dont want to send these to the front end, is there a way I can easly say I dont want these values or remove them before sending them?

```
    {
      "indistructable": true,
      "_id": "5e345c2dc84be8995a5b4cf2",
      "baseUri": "https://api.website.com/nameco8/",
      "company": "jnameco8",
      "description": "asset",
      "image": "myimage.png",
      "name": "jim",
      "supply": 100,
      "createdAt": "2020-01-31T16:56:13.816Z",
      "updatedAt": "2020-01-31T16:56:13.816Z",
      "__v": 0
    },
```

I have tried adding

```
    __v: {type: Number, select: false},
    _id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, select: false },
```

to my schema but when saving to the schema I then get an error
`"document must have an _id before saving"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I believe schemas are for writes to restrict unknown fields from being written to documents which make your documents look similar across your collection, but if you need to remove few fields in read then try projection in [.find()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html) :

```
const allAssets = await assets
        .find({ company }, {_id :0, __v:0})
        .sort([['createdAt', -1]])
        .exec();
      res.status(200).json({ assets: allAssets });
```

Comment: it's a double underscore before the v like __v but yes that worked perfectly thank you

Comment: @Bill : my bad typo :-) updated it. thanks.. Remembering my last issue - In case if someone is here for same, tried this answer & if it's not working then understand that for few versions of mongodb drivers you need to use it as `{projection:{_id:0, __v:0}}`..

Answer (score 0):

```
 Schema.find()
      .select("-_id -__v")
      .exec()
      .then(result =>{
      console.log(result);
      })
```

In addition to @whoami - fakeFaceTrueSoul's answer, you can also add multiple <" -fieldName "> to your select statement in find()